# JavaScript tweak code for loading HTML table instead of picture (PNG)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of code which loads an image. But my new resources will all be in HTML tables instead of the image of a table. Can you please help me tweak it? I'm wondering whether it's possible. So a couple of queries will combine an image name which I have stored as png files. But my new source will be .html simple 13 by 13 tables containing some data. This is the only way I can export it from my third party program. How can I change the function below so that it will load my HTML source instead of the image?

```
setImageSource: function() {
  if (isProductionEnvironment) {
    document.querySelector('#result-image-1').src = `/xx/xx/images/${imageName}.png`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#result-image-1').src = `https://xx/xx/images/${imageName}.png`;
  }
 
},
```

Thank you for your effort

Comment: i don't know what you want to do. do you have any kind of screenshots? or more code?

Comment: The user picks a make, a model, a year and a range 0-100%. After inputting range the name of the image will be something like volvo-v40-2012-50.png. I have all kind of pictures loaded (~2800). But now instead of loading a picture I want it to load a html table which I have stored in .html files. Also 2800+ tables. Hope this makes it a bit more clear

Comment: use a iframe and display the html file in there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on my assumption, instead of load an image, you want to load an .html file; right now you use an img tag with a src value according with the user input something like your code. Then now you wanna load html code, for that you can use iframe tag with a `src` value  or an object tag with a `data` value according with the user input.

iframe https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

object https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Something like this...

```
setIframeSource: function() {
  if (isProductionEnvironment) {
    document.querySelector('#result-iframe-1').src = `/xx/xx/images/${imageName}.html`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#result-iframe-1').src = `https://xx/xx/images/${imageName}.html`;
  }
},
setObjectData: function() {
  if (isProductionEnvironment) {
    document.querySelector('#result-object-1').data = `/xx/xx/images/${imageName}.html`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#result-object-1').data = `https://xx/xx/images/${imageName}.html`;
  }
},
```